# What's a more stylistically elegant way to assess a large number of Java string comparison conditions?

Tags: java, string, comparison

I have written the following string comparison operation for a feature in my app.

But I hate the way this looks and how unwieldy it is.

```
String foo = "abc";

if(!foo.startsWith("ba") && 
    !foo.equals("cab") && 
    !foo.equals("bca") && 
    !foo.equals("bbc") && 
    !foo.equals("ccb") && 
    !foo.equals("cca"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Is there a more elegant and perhaps more maintainable way to write something like this?

Comment: you could use a regex, but you still need to include all the conditions in the regex....

Comment: If you are going to have a lot of them you probably want to break it out into it's own method, other than that I don't think you have many elegant options.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regular expression.

```
private static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile(
                                 "(ba.*|cab|bca|bbc|ccb|cca)");

String foo = "abc";
if (!P.matcher(foo).matches())
```

Comment: Do you need `^` and/or `$` in there somewhere? `"aba"` should be legal, but will be matched by the `ba.*` portion.

Comment: @dlev, From the Javadoc `The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.` so `aba` will not be matched by `ba.*`

Comment: @dlev, the `find()` does what you suggested and you would have to add `^` and `$` if you wanted that. (or use matches())

Answer (score 6):

If you only have this condition once in your code, I would let it like this. If you have it several times, initialize a constant set:

```
private static final Set<String> STRINGS_TO_AVOID = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("cab", "bca", "bbc", "ccb", "cca")));

...

if (!foo.startsWith("ba") && !STRINGS_TO_AVOID.contains(foo)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex (ideally) or if/else block.  Here's a gentle introduction to Java regular expressions:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/

Answer (score 0):

With your example, you could use a HashSet to put all the Strings you want to compare.

Then you could simply type

```
 if (!foo.startsWith("ba") && !mySet.contains(foo)) { 
    //doSomething
 }
```

- Edit : Dang...  i was to late... someone else beat me. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that something like the following is more "elegant" than your original code.

```
if (!foo.matches("^ba.*|^cab$|^bca$|^bbc$|^ccb$|^cca$")) {
  // do something
}
```

I prefer the original since it is simplest, uses natural language that anyone can understand and therefore it is more maintainable...

Comment: I would argue that any more than two or three boolean expressions in a single "if" statement is a travesty.  The "matches()" is far, far superior!  It's also more efficient.

Comment: @paulsm4, on my computer the original example took 16832 nanoseconds to match whereas the regex example took 2727022 nanoseconds. If you compile the pattern first it takes 86044 nanos. Do you still believe that regex is far, far superior and more efficient? I don't think so. BTW, the stings_to_avoid method took 32896 nanos. Moreover, I asked my girlfriend (who is not into programming) and she agrees that the original example is by far easier to understand...